# Install Gentoo (Do you need Internet/Stage 3)

Tags: linux, gentoo, x86, x86-64

https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/install-gentoo

Do you need to download the stage3 tarballs to use Gentoo or can you do a minimal install w/o them?

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Media#Minimal_installation_CD

```
The image is maintained by Gentoo developers and allows anyone to install Gentoo if an active Internet connection is available.
```

Says you need an Internet connection while performing the minimal install. Do you still need Internet during install if you use the stage3 tarballs? If I install multiple times, I don't want to download the same packages each time...

Should I download stage 3 tarball or just the ISO?

Answer (score 1):

The installation CD is the base medium to bolt into in order to have all the necessary tools to reach the part of the install where you'll use the stage3 tarball.

The stage3 tarball is a precompiled minimal working system so you can chroot into it and have a working package manager / build chain to install the rest of the system, including the kernel.

Unless you're already further ahead in the install Handbook, you need the ISO.

As a side note, I'd strongly advise against attempting to deviate from the official Handbook if you're still that unfamiliar with Gentoo. Go through it at least once normally, once you understand what leads where and why, you'll be able to think about how to streamline things.

Comment: You could use any existing linux distribution as "base" system, and then download a stage tarball.  The minimal one is just a "minimal" distribution to use as a base.
Don't know if there is any "full" cds these days, but once upon a time you could get a CD that contained both stage, portage tree, and distfiles to get started.

Comment: While you *can* use pretty much any existing distribution, I would advise people unfamiliar with the handbook to stick with it at least once. If you're not comfortable enough to have to ask, you're better off having everything as explained in the handbook rather than having to adapt the handbook to your existing base system.